# Possible to have thin-clients with RDP GUI connected to Leopard Server?

Tags: linux, rdp, osx-leopard, thin-client

I'd like to ask if there is any solution to run thin client in Linux/Windows with RDP GUI connected to Leopard Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the defacto solution for terminal service-like access on OS X. [Aqua Connect.](http://www.aquaconnect.net/)

Comment: Thanks. But I need to run Linux clients, not Mac clients.

Comment: Did you bother to read the link? I presume not because you would have discovered that AquaConnect allows any software that is capable of establishing an RDP connection to connect to an OS X server.